# Fill an array the right way and get the maximum out of it

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, push

i am very new to Javascript and I struggle to find a solution.
I got an dynamically changing array called `pat`. The elements of the array have coordinates x and y.
So now, i want to use a loop to store all x values of all elements into a new array called `newArray`. And then after filled `newArray`, i wish to get the maximum value out of it. The problem is, that i currently struggle to use the `push` function in the right way. My code is below. Hope, someone can help. Thank you guys!

```
for ( i = 0; i < pat.length; i++ ) {
    console.log(pat[i].x);
    var newArray = pat.push[i];
    console.log(newArray);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) like that:

```
var newArray = []; // create an empty array

for (var i = 0; i < pat.length; i++) {
  newArray.push(pat[i].x); // push the x value of the current element to the array
};

var max = Math.max.apply(null, newArray); // calculate the maximum of all x values
```

A more functional approach using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) would be:

```
var newArray = pat.map(obj => obj.x);
var max = Math.max.apply(null, newArray);
```

PS: Are you sure you want to call the array `newArray`?

*Edit*: my solution to calculate the maximum works like this: [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) returns the highest value of all of its arguments. [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) calls `Math.max` with the array's elements as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud decrate the array outside the for loop, otherwise it will be re-declarate on each iteration. You can declarate the Array with the [array literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Array_literals) `var arrayName = [];`. To add elements to the array you should use `arrayName.`[push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)`(value)` method . To find the biggest number in the array we have to use `Math` this is built-in object that has properties and methods for mathematical constants and functions.
We need only `max` method from those object, which takes numbers as arguments, from which it returns the biggest one `Math.max(a, b, c, d ...)` while it takes only number we can't pass `Array` as an argument to it, to do so we can use the `apply` method which comes from [Function.prototype.apply(](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)) it calls a function with a given this value, and arguments provided as an array (or an array-like object).
That's how we can put the array as an arguments to the `Math.max.apply(thisArg, [argumentsAsArray]);` or `Math.max.apply(null, newArray);` in your case.

```
var newArray = []; // create an empty array outside the for loop
for ( i = 0; i < pat.length; i++ ){
   newArray.push(pat[i].x); // add new element to the array
}

console.log(newArray);

var max = Math.max.apply(null, newArray); // take biggest number from the array
console.log(max);
```

Comment: Although this my answer the question, code-only answers are frowned upon.  Please also provide an explanation to OP to explain your answer.  [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)